# Protractor actions().mouseMove command not working for firefox and IE, for chrome it works fine

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, browser-automation

I have been getting error for command mouseMove using actions class. The error only comes when I run the script on firefox and IE, with chrome it works fine.

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
browser.get("https://chercher.tech/practice/popups")
        // mouse hover on a submenu
        browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.id("sub-menu"))).perform()
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The 'action' functions where buggy for gecko driver for years. You can find plenty of opened issues in the Github. You can use this package for now (it includes mouseMove as well)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-firefox-support

The worst part about this is that most likely you will have to duplicate all your spec files in which you are going to use mouse actions for Firefox... Maybe someone will came up with some fancy solution on how to detect browser or pass some variable depending on what your capabilities are

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I found in the above link that they have been using coordinates to hover, is it possible to add a selenium locator instead of coordinates in mouseMove command?

Comment: I'm not sure. You can dig deeper in the packages code and see how it works. But if this function accepts only coordinates you can try to retrieve the coordinates first using the protractor's .getLocation(). (let elmPosition =  await element(by.id('my-id')).egtLocation()) Please let me know if it works for you

Comment: Adding the locators in this command did not worked for me. I would try using getLocation(). Thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 0):

try to Use:

```
await browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)', avatarButton);
```

where avatarButton is a selector

Answer (score 0):

You can use dispatchEvent (this works in Chrome and in Firefox).

```
it('tests tooltip on button with id myFirstButton', async() => {
    const button = await element(by.id('myFirstButton'));
    await browser.executeScript(`var ev = new MouseEvent('mouseenter');`
                                + 'arguments[0].dispatchEvent(ev);', button);
    /* now the tooltip should be visible ... */
    ...
});
```